# Python Twisted - How to set log levels for twisted.logger

Tags: python, logging, twisted

Twisted recently came out with a new logging module: `twisted.logger`.  I've read through the documentation[1], but I haven't been able to find where one sets the actual log level.  The section on log observers[2] suggests that you might configure a predicate to do this if you are explicitly configuring your own LogObservers, but I am not sure how I am supposed to set the log level if I am running my app using `twistd` using either the `--logfile` or `--syslog` options.

Am I missing something in the documentation?  Can someone provide a short example how I would use `twistd` and set the log level within my application to say, `INFO`?

[[1] howto/logger](http://twisted.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core/howto/logger.html)

[[2] howto/logger#provided-log-observers](http://twisted.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core/howto/logger.html#provided-log-observers)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063649/how-to-set-logging-level-in-twisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emitting at various log levels is done via the various emitter methods (`log.debug`, `log.warn`, etc.)

The new module was added in a way meant to keep existing functionality exactly the same as before, so the log observers in use by `twistd` as the same as they were before and are not (yet) set up to do filtering based on log levels.

Building that sort of functionality into `twistd`, as well as other goodies such as logging serialized JSON data instead of text (which can then be parsed and examined by software) are still forthcoming.

In the meantime, you can set up your own log observers that do this, but that does require writing some code.  You can write an observer that inspects the `log_level` key on inbound events, or use a `FilteringLogObserver` which will do that for you and forward the filtered events to your observer.  The docs you referenced above should help you get started with that, if you want to use this now.

There's a lot of potential here, such as being able to modify which log levels as passed along for specific modules at runtime, which is probably out of scope for `twistd` command-line options, but could be altered by a custom (eg. web) interface, or having only certain types of events go to a text log file and others sent via email, etc.

Basically, we've been focusing on not breaking existing clients of Twisted, but do expect more and better integration with this new functionality over time.

Comment: Setting a log level is a pretty common and basic thing. There should be a recommended way to do that for twisted applications.

Comment: FilteringLogObserver requires me to pass it an observer. How do I pass it an observer that means "whatever twistd was going to do before I added a filter"?